# Is it necessary to synchronize observables when observing on the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, system.reactive

Is this .Synchronize() needed? If not, when it is actually necessary to use?

```
_subject.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Synchronize().Subscribe(OnNext)
```

The reason I thought this might be necessary is because I am calling the subject's OnNext from multiple threads. I do want the OnNext method to be executed on the main thread, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Synchronize` extension method is used for two things:

1. To ensure that the observable that it is applied to follows the proper observable "contract" - i.e. `OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)`.
2. To ensure that each `OnNext` is serialized - no overlapping if called on different threads.

In your case though, you are synchronizing to the current context so the second point is handled for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In this case, do I still need to worry about your first point? Under what circumstances would that be an issue?

Comment: @user981225 - You generally never need to worry about the first point if you use the standard Rx operators. It's really only when you implement your own `IObservable<T>` that you hit badly behaved observables.